# Validation Failed For Required Entity That Doesn't Exist In Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

So I've put down android for the time being and decided to get back to my .Net roots and get familiar with ASP/MVC. However, I'm currently having this issue:

I've created a simple log in form, and the model behind it has a userID but it's a key that I'm going to generate via code so it's not got the required tag. Problem is when I go to register I get this error:

> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation
>   failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property
>   for more details. The validation errors are: The m_IdentityCode field
>   is required.

There is however no attribute specifying it's requirement. I've watched a few videos where people used the [key] attribute and it didn't produce the requirement issue so I'm not sure what's going on and would appreciate any help.

```
[Key]
public string m_IdentityCode { get; set; }
```

Edit;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserRegistration(UserAccountModel user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (AccountDatabaseContext context = new AccountDatabaseContext())
        {

            context.m_UserAccounts.Add(user);
            context.SaveChanges();

            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.Message = "You have successfully registered your account. Welcome.";
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: But when is that exception is thrown? In your controller? When you are going to add an entity to your DbSet your key property must have a value

Comment: It's in my controller, yes, when I add the user. I'm not sure why, it should be automatically set to one because I set it as 1 default in the sql..

Comment: Also @octavioccl I updated the post with the calling code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before add the user to your `DbSet` you need to set your Key property with a value:

```
    using (AccountDatabaseContext context = new AccountDatabaseContext())
    {
        user.m_IdentityCode="someValue";
        context.m_UserAccounts.Add(user);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Your issue is because that property by default is `null`, and when you call `SaveChanges` method, EF is going to validate your model and will notice you haven't set your key property.

Comment: Word, I legit just put in user.m_IdentityCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); and then saw you post this. Thanks for taking the time, Brother.

Comment: Especially since it was a such a stupid question. But I've been up for like 40+ hours so thanks for humoring me sir. :)